# Google Script to Local Project on computer

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have this code on script.google.com:

```
function myFunctionthis() {
var app = SpreadsheetApp;

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zELRy4eSE_FdyQLkDwKCo-0lYG6BeXSMT5MNZes9n-s/edit#gid=0&range=B2").getActiveSheet();

var temp = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();

return temp;


}
```

I'm using this code to get a value of a cell from a spreadsheet.
Now, I have a local project on my PC in JavaScript and PHP. I want to use this function to assign the value, returned by this function, to a variable in my local project.

In the local project:

```
var value1 =  myFunctionthis();
```

is not returning any output.

Comment: All I did was copy this chunk of code and paste it into the .js file that contained the variable I need to assign the value to. If i'm missing something, please let me know.

Comment: You need to use Google Sheets API to work with spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it will not work this way. You need to use Google’s Sheets API - as far as I know there isn’t any javascript implementation, but you  can work directly with their API or use [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)